# Application behave different if i run it from Android stuido or i instal it using apk created by Android studio

Tags: java

i have been making game for android in java using SurfaceView. It was working as expected but couple of weeks ago i started to have problem.
When i run game on device from Android studio everything is fine. 
[Pic1. run from Android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9Hbh.png)

When i tried install this app on the same device using apk file created by Android studio graphics is totaly out of way.
[pic2. install using apk file created by Android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1JDf.png)

Today i found out that if i install apk file when device is connected to computer and Android studio is on, the game install and run normally.

The only change i made last weeks which could be relevant - this variables used to be non static.

```
public static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
public static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
```

Any ideas, advice, helps pls?

Comment: I tried signet apk, still the same

Comment: thx for help. It was that variables.